# Assign javascript form value according to input

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, v-model

Hi I have got a little Fish Tank app whereby user can input a Fish type and give it a name.

Also, want to assign a feed weight amount according to the input ie Gold Fish = 0.1, Angel Fish = 0.2 etc so I can collect all and sent in json.

Here is the basic working code Ive got. (except for feed weight/feedMass) but only at moment puts in one value, and have to be able to put more in tank.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  props: {
    "Gold Fish": String,
    "Angel Fish": String,
    "Babel Fish": String
  },
  data: {
    fishType: '',
    fishName: '',
    feedMass: ''
  },
  methods: {
    getFormValues() {
      if (this.fishType === "Gold Fish") { // This doesn't work
        this.feedMass = 0.1
      }
      this.fishType = this.$refs.fishType.value // These do.
      this.fishName = this.$refs.fishName.value
      //this.feedMass = this.$refs.feedMass.value
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form>
    <h3>
      Input Gold Fish, Angel Fish or Babel Fish, and give it a name
    </h3>
    <input type="text" ref="fishType">
    <input type="text" ref="fishName">
    <input type="text" ref="feedMass">
    <button @click.prevent="getFormValues()">Get values</button>
  </form>
  <br /> Fish Type {{ fishType }}
  <br /> Fish Name {{ fishName }}
  <br /> Feed Weight {{ feedMass }}
</div>
```

The feed input is not needed as the weight is to be assigned according to different fish choice,

```
            • 0.1g for each Gold  fish
            • 0.2g for each Angel fish
            • 0.3g for each Babel fish
```

They might put in more than one Gold fish for eg so feedMass has to be culmulative, ie add all together.

Have got to collect all choices, 2 by user (type and name of fish), assign the weight and output as json to api.

The actual Jfiddle is at

[JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhostcom/p8o4um10/39/)

How to assign the weight according to fishType, perhaps in Tank class?

Tips welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution here is to define a `FishType` class as follows:

```
class FishType {
  name: string;
  feedWeight: number;
}
```

Then create an array of all the fish types you want:

```
const fishTypes: FishType[] = [
  {'Gold fish', 0.1},
  {'Angel fish', 0.2}
]
```

Now, when a user submits a fish type, you can simply fetch the right feed weight by using a filter for example:

```
const feedWeight = this.fishTypes.filter(t -> t.name.equalsIgnoreCase(this.$refs.fishType.value)).feedWeight;
```

**Note:** It might be useful to use the fishtypes in a dropdown, so that users cannot input non-existing fish types.

Comment: Got the class but called it Tank, in .ts class file in Nuxt it wont let me create the const fishTypes       -    '{ 'Gold fish': any; 0.1: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Tank'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''Gold fish'' does not exist in type 'Tank'.          const fishTypes: Tank[] = [
    {'Gold fish', 0.1},
    {'Angel fish', 0.2}
  ]

Comment: Have you tried using const fishTypes: FishType[] = [
  {name: 'Gold fish', feedWeight: 0.1}
]?

Comment: Got it mostly working now ,had to move on to other project, it is here https://github.com/xhostcom/vue-fish-tank.git  works except for the very last bit. Thanks.